# Paint a nine patch in a bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

I want to paint a Nine Patch into a Bitmap (filling all the space with the fill space). Thats my code but doesn't work. Can you help me?

```
    Bitmap bmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
    Canvas canvas= new Canvas(bmp);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    iv2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the bounds of your drawable before drawing:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
iv2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Although given that it looks like you're just using an `ImageView`, I'm not sure why you're not just setting it directly using [`setImageDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I dont use that method cause I need to paint more things in the bitmap before setting it in the ImageView